# iOS how to add date and name metadata to file stored on disk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, filesystems, metadata

Is there some way on iOS to add attributes to a file that I'm saving in the documents directory? Ideally I would have the file name, created date and duration.

I'm currently using two date formatters formatters and am using the filename to store date. This will quickly prove unmanageable if I need to store extra arguments.

```
//to save file
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyyHHmmss"];

//to display file date to the user
[_displayDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY HH:mm"];
```

**Is there a way to add metadata to file with the name and date?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extended file attributes can be used for application-specific data. To set an attribute, you'd use the setxattr function. Attributes are stored as name:data pairs and associated with the filesystem object. This [NSHipster post](http://nshipster.com/extended-file-attributes/) discusses the use of extended attributes.

Another approach, if you don't need the file itself to encapsulate all relevant information, is to maintain a database with metadata for each file.